# Can't import DWF File. seems like python addon error

Tags: python, add-on, import

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.3, Blender version is 2.82.

I installed the addon via user preferences, and would like to import a dwf file.
*(I converted it from DWG using ODA File converter to 2010 ASCII DXF Version)*.

Here's the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.82/scripts/addons/io_import_dxf/__init__.py", line 542, in execute
    proj_dxf, proj_scn, self.represent_thickness_and_width, self.import_atts, dxf_unit_scale)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.82/scripts/addons/io_import_dxf/__init__.py", line 120, in read
    errors = do.entities(os.path.basename(filename).replace(".dxf", ""), new_scene)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.82/scripts/addons/io_import_dxf/dxfimport/do.py", line 1633, in entities
    self._recenter(scene, name)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.82/scripts/addons/io_import_dxf/dxfimport/do.py", line 1400, in _recenter
    bpy.context.screen.scene = scene
AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'scene'
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Is this any problem I can fix? Or just wait for the update?

Comment: Hi. What add-on? Dxf?

Comment: Questionable if the addon is for 2.82.  Rather than setting `screen.scene` as in prior in 2.8 set `window.scene`. (_Explaining the error message_)  Can you provide a link to the addon you installed?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/scene_dxf.html.   this is the link I can find.